# All characters in string are escaped

Tags: javascript, c#-4.0

Can someone help me understand what kind of encoding (escape) was used to convert "f4adece2-6cc1-4adf-8740-8f71cdabd24b" to '\146\64\141\144\145\143\145\62\55\66\143\143\61\55\64\141\144\146\55\70\67\64\60\55\70\146\67\61\143\144\141\142\144\62\64\142'

Given '\146\64\141\144\145\143\145\62\55\66\143\143\61\55\64\141\144\146\55\70\67\64\60\55\70\146\67\61\143\144\141\142\144\62\64\142' how do I get back to my original string?

Answer (score 1):

After each backslash, convert any following digits to decimal. Encode as a single character with that ASCII value.